# Finding the amount of characters of all words in a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to find the total number of characters in the list of words, specifically this list:

```
words = ["alpha","omega","up","down","over","under","purple","red","blue","green"]
```

I've tried doing:

```
print "The size of the words in words[] is %d." % len(words)
```

but that just tells me how many words are in the list, which is 10.

Any help would be appreciated!

Sorry, I meant to mention that the class I'm doing this for is on the topic of for loops, so I was wondering if I had to implement a forloop to give me an answer, which is why the for loop tags are there.

Comment: Why is this tagged [loops] and [for-loop]? You haven't used a loop.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to mention that the class I'm doing this for is on the topic of for loops, so I was wondering if I had to implement a forloop to give me an answer.

Comment: @RyanRoss A `for` loop is one method to do it, there are quite a number of methods you could approach. In general, for any implementation you try to balance time complexity, space (memory) complexity, and readability among other things.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `len` function within a list comprehension, which will create a list of lengths

```
>>> words = ["alpha","omega","up","down","over","under","purple","red","blue","green"]
>>> [len(i) for i in words]
[5, 5, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5]
```

Then simply `sum` using a generator expression

```
>>> sum(len(i) for i in words)
43
```

If you really have your heart set on `for` loops.

```
total = 0
for word in words:
    total += len(word)

>>> print total
43
```

Comment: @acushner the expression will have to be completely evaluated to pass to `sum` anyway

Comment: that is incorrect. sum takes an iterable. if you do the list comprehension, FIRST, the entire list is created then sum iterates through that full list. if you do the gen expr, each element is generated on the fly.

Comment: well, sorry, what you said is technically correct. the expression does have to be completely evaluated, but in one case you create an entire list in memory and in the other case you just have a generator.

Comment: If the user only wants number of alphanumeric characters, then this might give incorrect answer when some strings in the list contains `space`. For example: `wrds = ["12 34","12","123 4"]` a better approach in that case will be `sum(sum(len(k) for k in i.split()) for i in wrds)`

Answer (score 3):

you can simply convert it to string.

```
print(len(str(words)))
```

Comment: This answer prints out 4 extra characters for every entry in words. Maybe print(len(str(words)) - 4*len(words)) would work better

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a word here and you want to count how many characters are present in a variable. The for loop below will be able to count that

```
var = 'Python'

    j = 0
    for i in var:
        j = j + 1
        print(j)
```